# Is there a system-wide spell checker for Ubuntu?

Tags: spell-checking, desktop-apps

I've read through several threads here but they don't answer the questions. There is absolutely no similarity between system language and a spell checker. On Windows, no such thing exists where if you're in a text editor, you won't have a red underline when you spell something wrong. Or if there is, it's extremelyl rare.

I'm using Notes-Up notebook for Ubuntu but whenever I spell something wrong, it doesn't let me know in any way, shape or form. There are just certain apps (most) in my experience that aren't detectable by a spell check on Ubuntu and I was wondering if there was an actual app or setting that can change this? Here's which apps I use that don't work with spell check.

- Skrifa
- Notes-Up

I don't use traditional office suite software, so I'm really hoping there's a workaround to get spell checker to work with any app.

Comment: There will never be something that works for every app since spell checking is internal to the software being used, not a system function. Have you checked whether those two tools specifically can support spell checking? Are there any relevant options?

Comment: Not necessarily true (for Windows). There are several software that I've tested that specifically scan software that aren't usually detected by internal/default spell checking systems. Especially the software I use on Linux, via the Windows version. From what I hear, though, when I ask around, it's usually a Linux issue, there are options on other OSes to bypass this issue. Guess I'll have to use my brain and focus more so that I don't make any mistakes. Haha. Thanks incredibly for being prompt and answering my question. :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/162280/disable-ubuntu-10-04-spell-check

Comment: @luv.preet Who said anything about disabling spell check? I said ENABLE. But thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not read properly, apologies. Open the software centre or synaptic (or the terminal) and search for aspell-hr, myspell-hr, aspell-nl and/or myspell-nl, hr being croation and nl being dutch, of course. The aspell packages are for the aspell spell checker, the myspell packages for the hunspell spell checker (compatible with myspell, hence the name), which is used as a plugin in several applications like libreoffice and firefox. Both can also be used as stand-alone tools. Maybe you can try this ! not sure

Comment: @luv.preet Thanks! :-) I'll try it out and see the best fit.